# how can a java thread communicate with an activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Android offers asynctask and handlers to communicate with an activity. But is it possible for a plain java thread to communicate with an activity and update an textview ?

I tried to write a basic thread t = new thread(); but it would not allow me to access any textviews nor any members of the activity

Comment: is there a reason why you can't use the AsyncTask construct?

Comment: because i am modifying old code , in which java threads are used. I do not want to add to the complexity

Comment: You would need to prove the trouble code and explain what it is/isn't doing. But yes you can use a new `Thread`

Comment: The problem with moving away from AsyncTask is that you are then put in charge of Thread management. You are leaving a lot of room for leaks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Thread`, but in order to do UI updates they have to be on the main thread of the application.  `AsyncTask` is a way to manage this for you, but you don't have to use it.  You can post `Runnable` objects to the UI thread via `Activity.runOnUiThread()` or even create a `Handler` while in the context of the main thread and post `Runnable` objects or send messages to it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a quick example I could shoot to you.  But, if you've already got a `Thread` implementation coded, just take the UI manipulation out of it and move it to a class derived from `Runnable` and call `this.runOnUiThread(theNewRunnable);`, assuming `this` is your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have access to the context:

```
context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // put your UI code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

here is an example of a bluetooth thread reading an incoming byte stream and then updating various Textviews using a message handler.

```
   public void run() {
    byte[] buffer; // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer = new byte[4];
                    mmOutStream.write(253);
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer,0,1);
                    mmOutStream.write(254);
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer,1,1);
                    mmOutStream.write(255);
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer,2,1);
                    mmOutStream.write(252);
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer,3,1);
                    // A message handler to deal with updating the text views
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, buffer).sendToTarget();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
             }
        }
     }
    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}


Handler mHandler = new Handler(){           
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch(msg.what){
                case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                    // Do Something;
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CONNECTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    /*
                     * For loop for test values
                     */
                    connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    connectedThread.start();
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                    int tempInt = byteToInt(readBuf[0]);
                    int speedInt = byteToInt(readBuf[1]);
                    int cadenceInt = byteToInt(readBuf[2]);
                    int distanceInt = byteToInt(readBuf[3]);
                    EditText temperatureData = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.temperatureData);
                    temperatureData.setText(Integer.toString(tempInt) + " C" );
                    EditText cadenceData = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cadence);
                    cadenceData.setText(Integer.toString(cadenceInt) + " rpm");
                    EditText speedData = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.speed_data);
                    speedData.setText(Integer.toString(speedInt) + " kph");
                    EditText distanceData = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.distanceCovered);
                    distanceData.setText(Double.toString(distanceMethod(distanceInt)) + " km");
            }
        }       
    };
```

In the above example various EditTexts are updated via the [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).  The handler was various "switch" like conditions and runs the code relevant to them if the condition is met.